# Chinese Remainder Theorem Consequence

Tags: number-theory

I am reviewing the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem and I am confused at one of the concluding sentences in my textbook. 
I understand why there is a solution for relatively prime $m,n$ such that for arbitrary integers $s,t$ that $ x \equiv s$ (mod m) and $x \equiv t$ (mod n) but the concluding sentence says that now the solution is  $ x$  mod(mn) . I do not understand this last statement.

Comment: In the proof we took mp+nq=1 by Bezout, and x=mpt+nqs then x-s=mpt+(nq-1)s=mp(t-s) thus x is equivalent to s mod m, and similarly for t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \equiv s \pmod m$ this implies that $x=mk+s$

Since $x \equiv t \mod n$ $mk \equiv t-s \pmod n$.

Let the inverse of $m$ $\pmod n$ be $l$.

Then notice that $k \equiv l(t-s) \pmod n$.

Thus $k=np+l(t-s)$.

Thus the solutions are of the form $mnp+kl(t-s)+s \equiv x \pmod {mn}$.

Note that $k,l,s$ are all fixed integers.

Thus, all solutions have the same residue divided by $mn$.

So for all solutions $q$, $q \equiv x \pmod {mn}$.

Comment: can you elaborate how you got that mnp + kl(t-s) + s $\equiv$ x mod (mn)

Comment: @JamesDickens Because we set $x=mk+s$ and $k=np+l(t-s)$.